# Disable vim E211: File no longer available

Tags: vim, macvim

After switching git branches, any files that existed on my previous branch raise an `E211: File "path/to/file.txt" no longer available` warning. I already know that and I find it very annoying that I'm warned about it every time I change the tab or pane that I'm focused on. Especially if I need to close 8 panes of files that no longer exist.

Is there any way to disable this warning or make it something that does not require any input to continue?

[image]

Comment: You say that all those warnings are annoying because you know that those files aren't there, but you are trying to open those files anyway. If you know that `path/to/file.txt` doesn't exist, don't switch to it.

Comment: I'm not trying to open them, they are already open. This error fires when switching panes to any open file

Answer (score 4):

You can tweak Vim's default behavior via the [`:help FileChangedShell`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#FileChangedShell) event.

> This autocommand is triggered for each changed file.  [...] If a FileChangedShell autocommand is present the warning message and prompt is not given.

Unfortunately, by defining an `:autocmd` (e.g. invoking a no-op like an empty `:execute`), you'll lose all the default functionality, and would have to re-implement parts of it (without the message on deletion) by inspecing `v:fcs_reason`. If the sledgehammer approach is fine for you, this will do:

```
:autocmd FileChangedShell * execute
```

Instead of `*`, you could enumerate all of your Git working copies, to make this a bit more targeted.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the suggestion. I'd rather not override and re-implement the defaults so I'll live with it for now

Comment: darn, i agree, ill have to live with this issue then for now also. my solution is to just `:qa!` and open vim again